# Changing to SQL Server state causes session object to be null

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, state

I am trying to change my application from `mode="StateServer"` to `mode="SqlServer"`. I've installed the `ASPState` database and all appears well.

When I change my `web.config` to the following:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" 
              sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;integrated security=true" 
              timeout="20" />
```

I start getting null errors whenever I access the `Session` object. I try doing something very simple, like the following:

```
Session["Blah"] = "Test";
```

And the session object is null. When I check the `filterContext` in the `OnActionExecuting` method, the `HttpContext.HttpContext.Session` object is null.  I'm not getting any SQL Server errors that a timeout or network connection isn't working. I didn't think I needed to change anything in the code when moving state providers.

Is there some other trick to getting it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I did all of the install during a visual studio session.  Closing Visual Studio and reopening the project made the session objects appear again.